# java socket messeging in a network

Tags: java, sockets, networking

this is the code which runs server in a thread infinitely and client for three times, this code works fine when i connect two laps in my mobile hot spot but then when i try to connect to my college WiFi(larger network)it is not working so
what should i do to get it right when i connect to college network

thanks in advance :)

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;   
import java.util.*;  
public class MyServer 
{  
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    new thser();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++ )
    {
            try
        {      
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            String mys=in.nextLine();
            Socket s=new Socket("112.168.43.134",6666);  
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
            dout.writeUTF(mys);  
            dout.flush();  
            dout.close();  
            s.close();  

        }
            catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   

    }

}  
}  

 class thser extends Thread
{

    public thser()
    {
        start();
    }

   public void run()
   {
    while(true)
    {
        try

        {  
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);  
            Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection   
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            String  str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
            System.out.println("message= "+str);  
            ss.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you are using the correct IPs in the college Wifi then the network may have disabled communication between the Wifi clients. In such a case you can only communicate to servers of your college or the Internet. You should ask the college network admin on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood the question right, but this is my answer:
Larger networks, who can be vulnerable to inside attacks, usually routes their connections so that two devices on their network cant speak directly to each other. This is the case at my school, witch makes me unable to host local servers on the network. This might be the problem in your case. The router in your collage may not permit your pc to send packets to any local ip on the network.

I think that this is most likely the problem. You can test this simply by trying to ping your phone or something, when both are on the collage network.

The program worked great on my computer :)

PS: Hope you remembered to change the ip on line 15, when you changed from your hotspot wifi to your collage wifi

Comment: so my college shd permit me to connect to the ip requested ? and can you explain the problem in your school in detail

Comment: Not sure what you meant with the first sentence. Is it a question, or a statement? Im very new to networking, and dont know all the terminology yet, but basically all packets sent on the network of my school are examined by a sort of firewall, and all packets who are addressed from a local ip and to a local ip is discarded. This makes it impossible for anything on the network to talk directly to each other.

Comment: yeah i understood thanks a lot, and i actually need to communicate with the computers which are on internet using java or javascript is there any way

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you mean. Could you put it in a context of usage? Do you need two computers on the  collage communicating between each other, without connection to the global web? Could you give an example of use?

Comment: if suppose i am having two ip's which may be any where in the world and i have to make them communicate

Comment: Generally you would have a third computer, a server at a fixed location. On the network the server is, you would do something called port forwarding. In your case you would forward port 6666 of your router to the local ip of the server. This allows any computer to connect to your computer through your routers ip. Then each of the two computers that would like to talk to each other, would connect to the server. On the server you would have a program that simply forwards the messages from one client to the other.

Comment: so the third computer which forwards messages from one client to another should permit the client request right? that is client should have permission to access that server ?

Comment: Yes. Don't see why you would have a server which no one would be allowed to access

Comment: Glad to hear :) If you liked my answer, please feel free to upvote some of them